# chmod o-x file system unable to boot

Tags: centos7, boot

As per title, I changed system file permissions in root and I'm unable to boot. Stuck at loading login gui. Is there anyway to revert this? I am able to access grub command line. Thank you

Comment: which specific file's permission you modified ? Try booting with ubuntu or centos live cd/iso and change the permission again.

Comment: 'Chmod o-x /'  if I do not have access to those?

Comment: is this a vm or physical machine ? try booting into single user mode then use chmod o+x /

Comment: It's a vm. Ok I'll try that tomorrow and get back to you, thanks

Comment: You can use any rescue CD like SysRescCD for this purpose. Just download it.

Answer (score 0):

If  you used the  `chmod --recursive`  the -R option, you likely have broken the permissions of a number of essential programs and directories.

Rebuilding a new operating system install and restoring data from backup is one way to recover.  If you have a backup of the entire OS, you might use that and skip reinstall.

Or, you can boot a rescue environment and fix manually. This likely will be very tedious work comparing to a working system. Possibly if all the affected files are owned by a package, [rpm --setperms   and --setugids   will help reset those.](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/reset-rhel-centos-fedora-package-file-permission.html)